# keras embedding layer modification for multiple time-steps with one feature

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, lstm, embedding

I have a sequence prediction problem in which, given the last `n` items in a sequence I need to predict next item. There are `N=60k` sequences for now and for each sequence `n`, I have `6 events` and I want to `predict next(7th in this case) event`. The dataset looks like this

```
seq_inputs = [
["AA1", "BB3", "CC4","DD5","AA2", "CC8", "CC11"], #CC11 is target
["FF1", "DD3", "FF6","KK8","AA5", "CC8", "AA2"]   #AA2 will be target
..
..
] # there are 60k of them i.e len(seq) = 60000
```

**What I have done till now:**

Uptill now, I casted it as next word prediction problem and used embedding+LSTm.

First I tokenise them and convert them in numeric form using `keras tokenizer.text_to_sequence()`

From this numeric converted sequence, I take the last one as target and first six as input (JUST DUMMY EXAMPLE BELOW)

```
seq_inputs = [
    [1, 10, 200, 5, 3, 90 ],
    [95, 15, 4,11,78, 43]
    ..
    ..
    ] 
targets = [40,3, ... , ... ]
```

And I convert targets to Categories as

```
targets = to_categorical(targets, num_classes=vocabulary_size)
```

SO, I feed it into embedding and LSTM as

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(vocabulary_size, 32, input_length=seq_len)) #seq_length
model.add(LSTM(80,return_sequences=True))
..
..
..
model.fit(train_inputs,train_targets,epochs=50,verbose=1,batch_size=32)
```

Currently, I have very bad test performance and I feel I am not utilising LSTM well for sequential task, so I want to convert this problem to `Many-to-One Sequence Problems with a Single Feature` where I will have 6 time steps with single feature for each sequence. for example

**Inputs (6 time steps and one feature for every sequence n in N(60k):**

```
seq = [[[ 1],
        [10],
         [200],
        [5],
         [3],
        [90],
         ],

       [[ 95],
        [15],
         [4],
        [11],
         [78],
        [43],
        ],
       ...
       ...
      ... #60,000 of them
      ]
```

**target**:

```
targets = [40,3, ... , ... ]
```

**Question**: How can I modify this network, specially embedding layer to take this shape of input where EACH seq/ row is 6 time-step and one feature only. Also, is my understanding correct about 6 time-steps and one future, if yes, What else I need to modify in the network.